# Problem with KDE Plasma and i3 x server won't start

Tags: debian, x11, xorg, kde, i3

Setup: debian 8 standard KDE (KDE4)

I wanted to try out i3 next to KDE

**What I did:**

```
apt-get install i3
```

**What it did:** (from /var/log/apt/history.log)

```
Install: libasync-interrupt-perl:amd64 (1.21-1+b2, automatic), i3:amd64 (4.13-1), libxcb-xrm0:amd64 (1.0-2, automatic), libev4:amd64 (1:4.22-1+b1, automatic), libanyevent-i3-perl:amd64 (0.16-1, automatic), dunst:amd64 (1.1.0-2+b1, automatic), i3-wm:amd64 (4.13-1, automatic), libxdg-basedir1:amd64 (1.2.0-1, automatic), libanyevent-perl:amd64 (7.130-2, automatic), libjson-xs-perl:amd64 (3.030-1, automatic), libev-perl:amd64 (4.22-1+b1, automatic), libguard-perl:amd64 (1.023-1+b2, automatic), libconfuse-common:amd64 (3.0+dfsg-2, automatic), libtypes-serialiser-perl:amd64 (1.0-1, automatic), libcommon-sense-perl:amd64 (3.74-2, automatic), i3lock:amd64 (2.8-1, automatic), i3status:amd64 (2.11-1, automatic), libconfuse1:amd64 (3.0+dfsg-2, automatic), suckless-tools:amd64 (42-2, automatic)

Remove: libpackage-stash-perl:amd64 (0.37-1), libcpan-meta-perl:amd64 (2.150010-1), libfreerdp-codec1.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-13), libnm-glib4:amd64 (1.6.2-3), alsa-base:amd64 (1.0.27+1), python-sip:amd64 (4.18.1+dfsg-2), libkutils4:amd64 (4:4.14.26-2), libwebp5:amd64 (0.4.1-1.2+b2), libpath-tiny-perl:amd64 (0.100-1), libwinpr-environment0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-13), libavformat56:amd64 (6:11.9-1~deb8u1), libcpan-changes-perl:amd64 (0.400002-1), libmoo-perl:amd64 (2.002005-1), libfollowupreminder4:amd64 (4:4.14.1-1), python-dbus-dev:amd64 (1.2.4-1), libpod-readme-perl:amd64 (1.1.2-1), libpackage-constants-perl:amd64 (0.06-1), libgphoto2-port10:amd64 (2.5.4-1.1+b2), liblistaller-glib0:amd64 (0.5.9-4), libsctp1:amd64 (1.0.17+dfsg-1+b1), libplist2:amd64 (1.11-3), libksignalplotter4:amd64 (4:4.11.13-2), libmodule-runtime-perl:amd64 (0.014-2), libchromaprint0:amd64 (1.2-1), libgroupsock1:amd64 (2014.01.13-1), python-wstools:amd64 (0.4.3-3), libmessagecore4:amd64 (4:4.14.10-7+b2), libtemplateparser4:amd64 (4:4.14.10-7+b2), libisccc90:amd64 (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u11), libparams-validate-perl:amd64 (1.26-1), libqoauth1:amd64 (1.0.1-2), liblist-moreutils-perl:amd64 (0.416-1+b1), libwinpr-library0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-13), libshp2:amd64 (1.4.0-1), libzip2:amd64 (0.11.2-1.2), libfile-slurp-perl:amd64 (9999.19-6), libtype-tiny-perl:amd64 (1.000005-1), libwinpr-rpc0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-13), libisccfg90:amd64 (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u11), libxapian22:amd64 (1.2.19-1+deb8u1), vlc-plugin-samba:amd64 (2.2.6-1~deb9u1), libqt5serialport5:amd64 (5.7.1~20161021-2), libgegl-0.2-0:amd64 (0.2.0-7+b1), listaller:amd64 (0.5.9-4), python-smbc:amd64 (1.0.15.6-1), libvncclient0:amd64 (0.9.9+dfsg2-6.1+deb8u2), libwinpr-synch0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-13), docutils-common:amd64 (0.13.1+dfsg-2), libportaudio2:amd64 (19.6.0-1), iproute:amd64 (1:4.9.0-1), kde-window-manager:amd64 (4:5.8.6-1), g++-4.9:amd64 (4.9.2-10), libsmokeqtdbus4-3:amd64 (4:4.14.3-1.1), libplasmagenericshell4:amd64 (4:4.11.13-2), libfreerdp-locale1.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-13), libgrantlee-gui0:amd64 (0.4.0-4), libdata-perl-perl:amd64 (0.002009-1), vlc-plugin-qt:amd64 (2.2.6-1~deb9u1), libespeak1:amd64 (1.48.04+dfsg-5+b1), libdata-optlist-perl:amd64 (0.110-1), libtry-tiny-perl:amd64 (0.28-1), libfreerdp-gdi1.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-13), libkpgp4:amd64 (4:4.14.10-7+b2), libbaloocore4:amd64 (4:4.14.3-3+b3), espeak-data:amd64 (1.48.04+dfsg-5+b1), libraw10:amd64 (0.16.0-9+deb8u2), libopenjpeg5:amd64 (1:1.5.2-3), libkwinglutils1abi2:amd64 (4:4.11.13-2), libvariable-magic-perl:amd64 (0.61-1), libkdepim4:amd64 (4:4.14.10-7+b2), libtommath0:amd64 (0.42.0-1.1), libavahi-glib1:amd64 (0.6.32-2), libboost-thread1.55.0:amd64 (1.55.0+dfsg-3), libfreerdp-crypto1.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-13), python-gi:amd64 (3.22.0-2), libwinpr-handle0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-13), libgetopt-long-descriptive-perl:amd64 (0.100-1), libumfpack5.6.2:amd64 (1:4.2.1-3), libprocessui4a:amd64 (4:4.11.13-2), libasprintf0c2:amd64 (0.19.3-2), libmoox-handlesvia-perl:amd64 (0.001008-2), libisc95:amd64 (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u11), libcamd2.3.1:amd64 (1:4.2.1-3), libkfilemetadata4:amd64 (4:4.14.3-1), libkactivities-models1:amd64 (4:4.13.3-1), marble-plugins:amd64 (4:16.08.3-1), libb-hooks-endofscope-perl:amd64 (0.21-1), python-dbus:amd64 (1.2.4-1+b1), libboost-system1.55.0:amd64 (1.55.0+dfsg-3), vlc-plugin-skins2:amd64 (2.2.6-1~deb9u1), libccolamd2.8.0:amd64 (1:4.2.1-3), htdig:amd64 (1:3.2.0b6-16+b1), libmodule-load-conditional-perl:amd64 (0.68-1), libwinpr-registry0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-13), python-kde4:amd64 (4:4.14.3-2+deb9u1), vlc-plugin-visualization:amd64 (2.2.6-1~deb9u1), liblwres90:amd64 (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u11), libksieve4:amd64 (4:4.14.1-1), libalgorithm-c3-perl:amd64 (0.10-1), vlc-l10n:amd64 (2.2.6-1~deb9u1), libqtlocation1:amd64 (1.2.0-3+b1), libqmi-glib1:amd64 (1.10.2-2), libdvbpsi9:amd64 (1.2.0-1), firebird2.5-common:amd64 (2.5.3.26778.ds4-5+deb8u1), libexporter-tiny-perl:amd64 (0.042-1), vlc-nox:amd64 (2.2.6-1~deb9u1), gdebi-core:amd64 (0.9.5.7+nmu1), kde-style-oxygen:amd64 (4:5.8.4-1), plasma-widget-folderview:amd64 (4:4.14.2-1), libbind9-90:amd64 (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u11), liborcus-0.8-0:amd64 (0.7.0+dfsg-9), libstreams0:amd64 (0.7.8-1.2+b2), python3-pyqt4:amd64 (4.11.4+dfsg-2+b1), libkleo4:amd64 (4:4.14.10-7+b2), libkalarmcal2:amd64 (4:4.14.10-7+b2), libkdecorations4abi2:amd64 (4:4.11.13-2), libclass-c3-xs-perl:amd64 (0.14-1+b1), libwinpr-interlocked0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-13), libwinpr-crt0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-13), libuuid-perl:amd64 (0.27-1), libnetworkmanagerqt1:amd64 (0.9.8.2-1), libqt4-test:amd64 (4:4.8.7+dfsg-11), libkateinterfaces4:amd64 (4:4.14.2-2), lksctp-tools:amd64 (1.0.17+dfsg-1+b1), libmodule-implementation-perl:amd64 (0.09-1), libpackage-stash-xs-perl:amd64 (0.28-3+b1), libnm-glib-vpn1:amd64 (1.6.2-3), libdevel-lexalias-perl:amd64 (0.05-1+b4), vlc-plugin-notify:amd64 (2.2.6-1~deb9u1), libwps-0.3-3:amd64 (0.3.0-2), libstrictures-perl:amd64 (2.000003-1), kde-style-oxygen-qt4:amd64 (4:5.8.4-1), libegl1-mesa-drivers:amd64 (13.0.6-1+b2), libfbclient2:amd64 (3.0.1.32609.ds4-14), libkdcraw-data:amd64 (4:15.08.0-1.1), docutils-doc:amd64 (0.13.1+dfsg-2), libwinpr-sysinfo0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-13), libsub-identify-perl:amd64 (0.12-2+b1), libkscreensaver5:amd64 (4:4.11.13-2), libestools2.1:amd64 (1:2.1~release-8), libdata-section-perl:amd64 (0.200006-1), libsub-exporter-perl:amd64 (0.986-1), libtype-tiny-xs-perl:amd64 (0.012-1+b2), python-docutils:amd64 (0.13.1+dfsg-2), libregexp-common-perl:amd64 (2016060801-1), libclass-xsaccessor-perl:amd64 (1.19-2+b7), libilmbase6:amd64 (1.0.1-6.1), libparams-util-perl:amd64 (1.07-3+b1), iio-sensor-proxy:amd64 (2.0-4), firebird2.5-common-doc:amd64 (2.5.3.26778.ds4-5+deb8u1), libdevel-caller-perl:amd64 (2.06-1+b4), libreoffice-sdbc-firebird:amd64 (1:4.3.3-2+deb8u7), libkscreen1:amd64 (1.0.5-1), kdm:amd64 (4:4.11.13-2), libntdb1:amd64 (1.0-9+b1), libintl-perl:amd64 (1.26-2), libcanberra-gtk3-module:amd64 (0.30-3), libelfg0:amd64 (0.8.13-5), libfbembed2.5:amd64 (2.5.3.26778.ds4-5+deb8u1), libsub-install-perl:amd64 (0.928-1), libpth20:amd64 (2.0.7-20+b2), libqt4-scripttools:amd64 (4:4.8.7+dfsg-11), libpostproc52:amd64 (6:0.git20120821-4), libvpx1:amd64 (1.3.0-3), libakonadi-kabc4:amd64 (4:4.14.10-7+b2), libunicode-utf8-perl:amd64 (0.60-1+b3), libwinpr-file0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-13), libtext-template-perl:amd64 (1.46-1), libkdgantt2-0:amd64 (4:4.14.10-7+b2), libokularcore5:amd64 (4:4.14.2-2), libqapt3-runtime:amd64 (3.0.2-1+b3), libcolamd2.8.0:amd64 (1:4.2.1-3), libturbojpeg1:amd64 (1:1.3.1-12), libwebpdemux1:amd64 (0.4.1-1.2+b2), libpod-latex-perl:amd64 (0.61-2), libfreerdp-common1.1.0:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-13), freespacenotifier:amd64 (4:4.11.13-2), geoclue-2.0:amd64 (2.4.5-1), libopenvg1-mesa:amd64 (10.3.2-1+deb8u1), libwinpr-sspi0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-13), libllvm3.5:amd64 (1:3.5-10), libkmanagesieve4:amd64 (4:4.14.1-1), libgeoclue-2-0:amd64 (2.4.5-1), libical1a:amd64 (1.0-1.3), libjim0.75:amd64 (0.75-1), libnm-util2:amd64 (1.6.2-3), libusbmuxd2:amd64 (1.0.9-1), libopenraw1:amd64 (0.0.9-3.5+b2), plasma-scriptengine-webkit:amd64 (4:4.11.13-2), libkgapi2-2:amd64 (2.2.0-1), plasma-scriptengine-python:amd64 (4:4.11.13-2), kdepimlibs-kio-plugins:amd64 (4:4.14.10-7+b2), libmessageviewer4:amd64 (4:4.14.10-7+b2), appstream-index:amd64 (0.10.6-2), liblog-message-perl:amd64 (0.8-1), libmarblewidget-qt5-25:amd64 (4:16.08.3-1), libparams-classify-perl:amd64 (0.013-6+b1), libqapt-runtime:amd64 (1.3.0-2.1), libclass-method-modifiers-perl:amd64 (2.12-1), libkimap4:amd64 (4:4.14.10-7+b2), libbaloofiles4:amd64 (4:4.14.3-3+b3), libgee-0.8-2:amd64 (0.18.1-1), libx264-142:amd64 (2:0.142.2431+gita5831aa-1+b2), libcholmod2.1.2:amd64 (1:4.2.1-3), marble-data:amd64 (4:16.08.3-1), libstdc++-4.9-dev:amd64 (4.9.2-10), python-soappy:amd64 (0.12.22-1), libimobiledevice4:amd64 (1.1.6+dfsg-3.1), libsmokeqtopengl4-3:amd64 (4:4.14.3-1.1), libkdcraw23:amd64 (4:15.08.0-1.1), pkg-config:amd64 (0.29-4+b1), librole-tiny-perl:amd64 (2.000005-1), firebird2.5-server-common:amd64 (2.5.3.26778.ds4-5+deb8u1), libastro1:amd64 (4:16.08.3-1), libterm-ui-perl:amd64 (0.46-1), libamd2.3.1:amd64 (1:4.2.1-3), libfreerdp-core1.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-13), libsmokeqtxml4-3:amd64 (4:4.14.3-1.1), python-roman:amd64 (2.0.0-2), ruby-qt4:amd64 (4:4.14.3-1+b3), libgif4:amd64 (4.1.6-11+deb8u1), python-pygments:amd64 (2.2.0+dfsg-1), libqapt1:amd64 (1.3.0-2.1), libqapt3:amd64 (3.0.2-1+b3), libwinpr-utils0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-13), libbaloopim4:amd64 (4:4.14.3-3+b3), libkontactinterface4a:amd64 (4:4.14.10-7+b2), libio-stringy-perl:amd64 (2.111-2), libbasicusageenvironment0:amd64 (2014.01.13-1), libimport-into-perl:amd64 (1.002005-1), libavcodec56:amd64 (6:11.9-1~deb8u1), libnamespace-clean-perl:amd64 (0.27-1), libpimcommon4:amd64 (4:4.14.10-7+b2), libktnef4:amd64 (4:4.14.10-7+b2), python-defusedxml:amd64 (0.4.1-2), libpackagekitqt4-0:amd64 (0.9.5-1), libdevel-globaldestruction-perl:amd64 (0.14-1), libwinpr-dsparse0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-13), libdbus-1-dev:amd64 (1.10.18-1), libkwinglesutils1:amd64 (4:4.11.13-2), vlc:amd64 (2.2.6-1~deb9u1), libavutil54:amd64 (6:11.9-1~deb8u1), kde-wallpapers:amd64 (4:15.04.2-1), libkwineffects1abi5:amd64 (4:4.11.13-2), libwinpr-input0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-13), libmodemmanagerqt1:amd64 (1.0.1-2), libakonadi-notes4:amd64 (4:4.14.10-7+b2), libcanberra-gtk3-0:amd64 (0.30-3), liblircclient0:amd64 (0.9.4c-9), libmodule-signature-perl:amd64 (0.81-1), libtext-soundex-perl:amd64 (3.4-1+b4), libwebpmux1:amd64 (0.4.1-1.2+b2), libfreerdp-utils1.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-13), libwinpr-heap0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-13), python-qt4-dbus:amd64 (4.11.4+dfsg-2+b1), libcalendarsupport4:amd64 (4:4.14.10-7+b2), liboath0:amd64 (2.6.1-1+b2), libswscale3:amd64 (6:11.9-1~deb8u1), libwebrtc-audio-processing-0:amd64 (0.1-3), liblog-message-simple-perl:amd64 (0.10-2), libbalooxapian4:amd64 (4:4.14.3-3+b3), libpadwalker-perl:amd64 (2.2-2+b1), libopenexr6:amd64 (1.6.1-8), python-libxml2:amd64 (2.9.4+dfsg1-2.2), libkblog4:amd64 (4:4.14.10-7+b2), kde-base-artwork:amd64 (4:4.11.5-1), libfreerdp-cache1.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-13), libdns100:amd64 (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u11), libwinpr-path0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-13), libkdepimdbusinterfaces4:amd64 (4:4.14.10-7+b2), libarchive-extract-perl:amd64 (0.80-1), qapt-batch:amd64 (3.0.2-1+b3), libhunspell-1.3-0:amd64 (1.3.3-3), vlc-plugin-video-splitter:amd64 (2.2.6-1~deb9u1), libglew1.10:amd64 (1.10.0-3), libenca0:amd64 (1.19-1+b1), libqt4-help:amd64 (4:4.8.7+dfsg-11), libmusicbrainz5-1:amd64 (5.1.0-2), libmsn0.3:amd64 (4.2-2), python3-pykde4:amd64 (4:4.14.3-2+deb9u1), libfreerdp-rail1.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-13), libbalooqueryparser4:amd64 (4:4.14.3-3+b3), libsoftware-license-perl:amd64 (0.103012-1), libkcal4:amd64 (4:4.14.10-7+b2), libsmokeqtsvg4-3:amd64 (4:4.14.3-1.1), kde-wallpapers-default:amd64 (4:15.04.2-1), liblivemedia23:amd64 (2014.01.13-1), libmodplug1:amd64 (1:0.8.8.5-3), imagemagick-common:amd64 (8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-11+deb9u1), libjasper1:amd64 (1.900.1-debian1-2.4+deb8u3), libakonadi-kcal4:amd64 (4:4.14.10-7+b2), libappstream1:amd64 (0.7.3-1), libjsoncpp0:amd64 (0.6.0~rc2-3.1), libwinpr-thread0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-13), libmodule-pluggable-perl:amd64 (5.2-1), libsub-exporter-progressive-perl:amd64 (0.001013-1), kde-workspace-kgreet-plugins:amd64 (4:4.11.13-2), libgrantlee-core0:amd64 (0.4.0-4), libqt5positioning5:amd64 (5.7.1-1), firebird3.0-common-doc:amd64 (3.0.1.32609.ds4-14), libqtassistantclient4:amd64 (4.6.3-7+b1), libsendlater4:amd64 (4:4.14.10-7+b2), firebird3.0-common:amd64 (3.0.1.32609.ds4-14), lockfile-progs:amd64 (0.1.17+b1), libexiv2-13:amd64 (0.24-4.1), libmessagecomposer4:amd64 (4:4.14.10-7+b2), plasma-scriptengine-superkaramba:amd64 (4:4.14.2-1), libkephal4abi1:amd64 (4:4.11.13-2), libpoppler46:amd64 (0.26.5-2+deb8u1), libquazip1:amd64 (0.7.2-1), libpod-markdown-perl:amd64 (3.005000-1), libbaloowidgets4:amd64 (4:4.14.0-1), libfreerdp-client1.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-13), libxcb-xtest0:amd64 (1.12-1), libqgpgme1:amd64 (4:4.14.10-7+b2), libintl-xs-perl:amd64 (1.26-2+b1), libkmbox4:amd64 (4:4.14.10-7+b2), python-cups:amd64 (1.9.73-1), libclass-c3-perl:amd64 (0.32-1), libpng12-0:amd64 (1.2.50-2+deb8u3), fonts-freefont-ttf:amd64 (20120503-6), libsmokeqtsql4-3:amd64 (4:4.14.3-1.1), libwinpr-pool0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-13), libqextserialport1:amd64 (1.2.0~rc1+git7-g3be3fbf-1+b1), python-pil:amd64 (4.0.0-4), libavresample2:amd64 (6:11.9-1~deb8u1), libwinpr-crypto0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-13), libqtruby4shared2:amd64 (4:4.14.3-1+b3), libflite1:amd64 (2.0.0-release-3+b1), libusageenvironment1:amd64 (2014.01.13-1), libincidenceeditorsng4:amd64 (4:4.14.10-7+b2), libmro-compat-perl:amd64 (0.12-1), libschroedinger-1.0-0:amd64 (1.0.11-2.1), libnamespace-autoclean-perl:amd64 (0.28-1), python-qt4:amd64 (4.11.4+dfsg-2+b1), libmodule-build-perl:amd64 (0.422000-1), libtidy-0.99-0:amd64 (20091223cvs-1.4+deb8u1), libfreerdp-primitives1.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-13), libboost-program-options1.55.0:amd64 (1.55.0+dfsg-3)
```

I saw the removes packages too late. I thought it were packages that were installed for i3. I let it run anyways.

**The problem:**

After a logout, `X` won't start, I just get a console ... However I can start `X` fine with:

```
export DISPLAY=0:0; startx
```

*Note: I need to explicitly export DISPLAY, without the export, startx won't work*

**What I want:**

I would like to start KDE again as it used to be! Where do I need to look to get it working again?

Comment: Run `sudo update-alternatives --config x-session-manager` then choose kde

Comment: Hi @GAD3R it tells me `There is only one alternative in link group x-session-manager ... /usr/bin/startkde Nothing to configure.`

Answer (score 1):

To create the default /etc/alternatives/x-session-manager, what needs to be done is apply update-alternatives and register window managers that do not do this by default.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/x-session-manager" "x-session-manager" "/usr/bin/i3" 2
```

Then:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-session-manager
```

Comment: I still didn't get it to auto start but i3 now starts. Also the update-alternatives are set to manual and kde was set to auto on 0 but did not start....